# Mysql sum group by query in laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to convert a query to eloquent or find a way to use it in a laravel controller.

The query is:

```
select employee, workdate, sum(actualhours) 
from ts_data group by employee, workdate;"
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: $workhoursData = TsData::select('employee', 'workdate', 'sum(actualhours)' )
            ->groupBy('employee', 'workdate')
            ->get();
and inserting the query raw

Comment: Please add all attempts to the question itself, containing an explanation about what is not working yet with the given code

Comment: I already got my answer, Thx anyway for the help will write my questions better next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Eloquent Model :

```
$records = TsData::select(
    'employee',
    'workdate',
    \DB::raw('sum(actualhours) as sumhours')
)
->groupBy('employee', 'workdate')
->get();
```

or using DB Facade :

```
$records = \DB::table('ts_data')->select(
    'employee',
    'workdate',
    \DB::raw('sum(actualhours) as sumhours')
)
->groupBy('employee', 'workdate')
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, I had thied it like this before but instead of DB i used my TsData and then it gave an error